# How to pass a variable to sprintf() function

Tags: r, printf

I would like to pass a constant to `sprintf()` function like:

This works:

```
sprintf("%.2f", pi)
[1] "3.14"
```

Now I would like to replace 2 by a constant x say 4:

```
x <- 4
sprintf("%.xf", pi)

Error in sprintf("%.xf", pi) : 
  invalid format '%.x'; use format %f, %e, %g or %a for numeric objects
```

Expected output:

```
[1] "3.1416"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an asterisk `*` to set the precision via argument in the format string:

```
x <- 4
sprintf("%.*f", x, pi)
[1] "3.1416"
```